# WooCommerce - send email when order was created

Tags: php, html, wordpress, email, woocommerce

I am trying to send emails to multiple email adresses when order was placed. I am using **woocommerce_thankyou** hook. But emails simply not sending.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', function( $order_id ){
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $paymentType = $order->payment_method_title;
    $firstName = $order->billing_first_name;
    $lastName = $order->billing_last_name;
    $billing_address = $order->billing_address_1;
    $billing_address2 = $order->billing_address_2;
    $billing_postcode = $order->billing_postcode;
    $billing_city = $order->billing_city;
    $billing_country = $order->billing_country;
    $billing_email = $order->billing_email;
    $billing_phone = $order->billing_phone;
    $totalRefunded = $order->get_total_refunded();
    $totalTaxRefunded = $order->get_total_tax_refunded();
    $totalShippingRefunded = $order->get_total_shipping_refunded();
    $total = $order->get_order_currency() . $order->get_total();
    $notes = $order->get_customer_order_notes();
    $company = $order->billing_company;
    $orderItems = $order->get_items();
    $subject = 'Order ' . $order_id . ' was placed';

    $message = '';
    $message .= "Payment Type: $paymentType<br>";
    $message .= "First Name: $firstName<br>";
    $message .= "Last Name: $lastName<br>";
    $message .= "Adress1: $billing_address<br>";
    $message .= "Adress2: $billing_address2<br>";
    $message .= "Post Code: $billing_postcode<br>";
    $message .= "City: $billing_city<br>";
    $message .= "Country: $billing_country<br>";
    $message .= "Email: $billing_email<br>";
    $message .= "Phone: $billing_phone<br>";
    $message .= "Total Refunded: $totalRefunded<br>";
    $message .= "Total Tax Refunded: $totalTaxRefunded<br>";
    $message .= "Company: $company<br>";
    $message .= "Order Notes: $notes->post_excerpt<br>";
    $message .= "Total Shipping Refunded: $totalShippingRefunded<br><br>";
    foreach($orderItems as $product) {
        $message .= $product['name'] . ' x' . $product['qty'] . '<br>'; 
    }
    $message .= "<br>Total: $total";
    $headers  = "Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-1251 \r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: post@test.com' . "\r\n" .
    "Reply-To: $billing_email" . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    mail(get_option('ordemails'), $subject, $message, $headers);
});
```

`get_option('ordemails')` is a string which contain email addresses separated by comma(test@test.com, test2@test.com)

Comment: `get_option('ordemails')` is added by you.?

Comment: yes and it return string 'email@test.com,emailtwo@test.com'

Comment: Ok.! I just had doubt its `ordermails` or `ordemails`

Comment: Are other woocommerce and wordpress emails being sent out from your site? Have you tried with wp_mail() function?